# Existe alguma forma de baixar um vídeo do Youtube usando o urllib?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe alguma forma de baixar um vídeo no youtube usando o `urllib` em Python?

Fiz um teste, mas não funciona (apenas um exemplo):

```
import urllib.request


youtube = ""

pagina = urllib.request.urlopen(youtube)

urllib.request.urlretrieve("", "video.mp4")
```

Comment: Assim, você estaria abrindo a página do vídeo, e não o arquivo em si, pelo que entendi.

Comment: Boa noite Jefferson, a resposta tem algum problema? Faltou algo?

Comment: Não, obrigado pela atenção. Consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: @Jefferson_Andr então se uma das respostas resolveu o problema poderia marcar a que se adequou ao seu caso como correta? Clicando no sinal de checked verde ao lado da resposta

Answer (score 9):

> **Nota:** Vale lembrar que o Youtube tem termos e condições, se os videos não são seus eu não recomendo fazer isto, como o [**Wallace disse**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/174669/3635)

Existe uma lib livre de dependencias chamada [pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube), instale usando o PIP, digite no terminal ou cmd:

```
pip install pytube
```

Exemplo de script:

```
from pytube import YouTube

# Esta parte não é necessária é apenas usada para entender o exemplo
from pprint import pprint

yt = YouTube("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y")

# Uma vez selecionado você pode ver todos formatos e resoluções disponíveis do video que deseja acessar

print(yt.get_videos())

# Exemplos de saídas possíveis

# [<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p>,
#  <Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 240p>,
#  <Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 360p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 360p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p>,
#  <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 360p>,
#  <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 480p>]

# O nome do video é automaticamente gerado a partir do titulo, mas você pode sobreescrever

# view the auto generated filename:
print(yt.filename)

# Pulp Fiction - Dancing Scene [HD]

# Renomeia:
yt.set_filename('Dancing Scene from Pulp Fiction')

# Você pode ficar a lista por tipo
print(yt.filter('flv'))

# [<Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 360p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>]

# Note que a lista é ordenada da menor resolução para maior
# Se esta procurando a maior resolução pelo formato faça isso:

print(yt.filter('mp4')[-1])

#Saída:
# <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p>

# Você pode ver todos formatos por resolução
print(yt.filter(resolution='480p'))

# [<Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>,
#  <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 480p>]

# E pode pegar um video por resolução e formato

video = yt.get('mp4', '720p')

# NOTE: get() só irá reconhecer os formatos e resoluções disponiveis

print(yt.videos)

#[<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p>,
# <Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 240p>,
# <Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 360p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 360p>,
# <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p>,
# <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 360p>,
# <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 480p>]

# Since we have two H.264 (.mp4) available to us... now if we try to call get()
# on mp4...

video = yt.get('mp4')
# MultipleObjectsReturned: 2 videos met criteria.

# In this case, we'll need to specify both the codec (mp4) and resolution
# (either 360p or 720p).

# Okay, let's download it! (a destination directory is required)
video.download('/tmp/')
```

### Por linha de comando:

Especifica a resolução:

```
$ pytube -r 720p http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y
```

Especifica aonde deseja salvar:

```
$ pytube -e mp4 -p ~/Downloads/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y
```

Especifica nome para ser salvo:

```
$ pytube -e mp4 -f Dancing Scene from Pulp Fiction http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y
```

Especifica a resolução e o formato desejado:

```
$ pytube -e mp4 -r 720p http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y
```

Answer (score 4):

Parece que de acordo com o [Termo de Uso](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms), não é legal baixar vídeos do Youtube.

<sub>Leia o item 5, com o título: *"Uso de conteúdo"*, item *B*.</sub>

Provavelmente, não vai haver alguma API (pelo menos políticamente correta) que ofereça suporte para isso.

Nessa [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081778/3096922), também fala sobre isso.

Comment: Eu ia citar isso :), mas já que o fez estou de acordo +1

Comment: Sei que isso não responde diretamente à pergunta, mas é importante destacar.

Comment: Eu apenos vou fazer um teste e ver como funciona. O vídeo utilizado será meu.

Comment: @Jefferson_Andr por mim tudo bem. Eu só quis deixar esse pequeno lembrete. Afinal de contas, sua pergunta será vista por outras pessoas interessadas no mesmo assunto. Então eu preferi fazer o "papel do chato", para elas terem consciência de que "tem como fazer", mas não é legalizado.

Comment: @Jefferson_Andr considere isto uma nota para futuros visitantes ;)